# MPI Terminal Help manual..!

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 15.04, c++, mpi

Is there is any possible way to get a developer manual help for the MPI commands in terminal. i tried `mpi --help` and `mpich --help` (because the mpi version command looks like `mpich --version`)but no use. So, what is the terminal command to get the manual help for mpi?. I'm expecting something like, to know the 'MPI_Send', it should give some thing like this:-

```
MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag,MPI_Comm comm)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For documentation of the individual functions provided by the OpenMPI library, you will need to install the `openmpi-doc` package, either from the Software Center or via a terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-doc
```

For MPICH I believe the corresponding package is `mpich2-doc` or `mpich-doc`.

Then the functions' man pages should be available as usual e.g. `man MPI_Send`

```
MPI_Send(3)                        Open MPI                        MPI_Send(3)

NAME
       MPI_Send - Performs a standard-mode blocking send.

SYNTAX
C Syntax
       #include <mpi.h>
       int MPI_Send(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest,
            int tag, MPI_Comm comm)

<snip>
```